# R: 3D surface plot from 2D matrix, complicated dimensions

Tags: r, plot, 3d, surface

I have the the following matrix: 

   `d          p1       p2       ... until p1804
   170        1.4      456
   300        1.7      236
   to 6456    ...      ...`

The values in the matrix have a maximum of 2000. I would like to make a surface plot out of it, but I struggle to deal with the dimensions. Is there a simple way to draw a surface plot in which

y-axis = d (ranging from 0 to 6456)

x-axis = p (p1 to p1804)

z-axis = respective matrix value (0 to 2000)

?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried `image(x)`?

Comment: thanks. but then I get a 2d-grid. Or did I miss anything?

Comment: Once you get `image(x)` to work, there's a `plot3D` function that can convert a raster (which is similar to image) to a 3D plot.